# Jenkinsでのdeployの方法

Tags: git, jenkins, デプロイ

今jenkinsの勉強をしています。
かなり初心者です。
gitにpushしたらJenkinsのジョブが走り自動的にビルドなりデプロイしてくれるまでは理解できました。
そもそもJenkinsにはもとからdeploy jobがデフォルトであるのでしょうか？
Configureを書き加えると特定の場所にdeployできるようになったりしませんか？
新しくdeploy jobを自分で作成しないとjenkinsでのdeployはできるようにならないのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

まずは端的に

> そもそもJenkinsにはもとからdeploy jobがデフォルトであるのでしょうか？
>   Configureを書き加えると特定の場所にdeployできるようになったりしませんか？ 新しくdeploy
>   jobを自分で作成しないとjenkinsでのdeployはできるようにならないのでしょうか？

もとからデプロイ可能なdeployjobの用意はありません。
基本は自らdeployのジョブを記述する必要があります。

https://jenkins.io/doc/
Jenkinsのドキュメントの最初にあるように

> Jenkins is a self-contained, open source automation server which can
>   be used to automate all sorts of tasks related to building, testing,
>   and delivering or deploying software.

「ソフトウェアの構築、テスト、配信または展開に関連するあらゆる種類のタスクを自動化するために使用できます。」
もともとあるタスクを自動化するためのツールであり、デプロイをするためのソフトウェアではありません。
そのためあくまで手動で行っているタスクを自動化して管理するところが得意なソフトウェアです。

なのでソフトウェアのデプロイの知識は自ら習得して、Jenkinsに設定していく必要があります。
ただし、ソフトウェアのデプロイの実例はもちろんのことJenkinsの特定のビルドやデプロイの実例もWebに豊富にあるのでほとんど困らないと思います。

まずは試してみましょう。困ったことがあったらまた質問してみてください。
楽しいCI/CDライフを！